# How to call method in returned class

Tags: c#

I have a function to return me the class instance. Here it is:

```
public class Warrior{
    private Type GetSpec()
    {

        if ((WarriorSpecs)charData.CharacterSpec == WarriorSpecs.Barbarian)
        {
            return new Barbarian(charData).GetType();
        }
        if ((WarriorSpecs)charData.CharacterSpec == WarriorSpecs.Guardian)
        {
            return new Guardian(charData).GetType();
        }
        if ((WarriorSpecs)charData.CharacterSpec == WarriorSpecs.Knight)
        {
            return new Knight(charData).GetType();
        }

        return this.GetType();
    }
}
```

All those classes `Barbarian`,`Guardian`,`Knight` are child classes of the class `Warrior`.

My question is why I cannot do the following:

```
public void FunctionInWarriorClass(){
    GetSpec.AnotherVoidInWarriorClass();
}
```

All I want is `GetSpec` to return an instance of any of those classes which are child classes and then call a function declared in `Warrior` class. Is that even possible?

Comment: Two reasons: 1) `GetSpec` can't be used like a property you have to use `GetSpec()`. 2) Even after you do that, you won't be able to access a method in the class because it returns a `Type` variable, not an instance of the class.

Comment: If `charData` is an instance of a `Warrior` class, you can just return `charData.GetTpe()`.

Comment: Why are you returning `Type` and not the instance you have created? If you want type, why aren't you returning `typeof(Knight)`, etc. rather than creating a new instance and calling `GetType()`?

Comment: `private Warrior GetSpec()` ... `return new Knight(charData)`

Comment: Also, if `Barbarian` is a subclass of `Warrior`, it can call all `public` or `protected` methods of `Warrior`. As you can see, it's not clear what exactly you want to do. Maybe you can give us a broader picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: [Required reading](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because GetSpec() return a Type object not a Warrior subclass.

Try this:

```
private Warrior GetSpec()

{

    if ((WarriorSpecs)charData.CharacterSpec == WarriorSpecs.Barbarian)
    {
        return new Barbarian(charData);
    }
    if ((WarriorSpecs)charData.CharacterSpec == WarriorSpecs.Guardian)
    {
        return new Guardian(charData);
    }
    if ((WarriorSpecs)charData.CharacterSpec == WarriorSpecs.Knight)
    {
        return new Knight(charData);
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: That was what I needed.